# How to forward a REST request to another resource?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

In my current architecture, I have a JAX-RS resource that sits behind:

```
/categories
/categories/{catId}
```

that's implemented like this:

```java
@Path("/categories")
@Produces("application/json")
public class CategoryResourcesApi {

    @GET
    public Response getCategories() {
        // ...
    }

    @GET @Path("/{catId}")
    public Response getCategory(@PathParam("catId") String catId) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

and another one that serves:

```
/products
/products/{prodId}
```

and has a similar implementation:

```java
@Path("/products")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ProductResourcesApi {

    @GET
    public Response getProducts() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

Apart from these straightforward paths, I also need to serve these:

```
/categories/{catId}/products
/categories/{catId}/products/{prodId}
```

which would be products related to a specific category.

The most natural thing to do would be make `ProductResourcesApi` serve them, but by the way I understand the JAX-RS annotations structure, this can only be served by `CategoryResourcesApi` (or eventually by a third class, I think).

I'm using `@Context` and other annotations in my resource implementations, so a direct `new ProductResourcesAPI().getProducts()` wouldn't work, I guess.

Is there any way to forward from one resource path to another within the JAX-RS (or Jersey) framework? What other options do I have? I'd like to keep all this easily maintainable if possible, that's why I chose one resource for each root path with subresources within.

Comment: Well, if you cannot put it together with JAX-RS then you may think about using plain servlets (with routing in web.xml) and use GSON (or something similar) to create the JSON output. It may need a bit more hand-written code but you gain flexibility.

Comment: @erosb Not an option: apart from the easiness offered by those frameworks, I'm using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) for API documentation, which integrates with them to generate the docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this you can use [Sub-resource locators](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2464), which is basically a method in the resource class that returns another resource class. The thing about the examples in the link is that they instantiate the resource class themselves, for example

```
@Path("/item")
public class ItemResource {
    @Path("content")
    public ItemContentResource getItemContentResource() {
        return new ItemContentResource();
    }
}

public class ItemContentResource {
    @PUT
    @Path("{version}")
    public void put(@PathParam("version") int version)
    }
}
```

which works, but I am not sure if it preserves injections, for instance if you wanted to inject `@Context UriInfo` into a field in `ItemContentResource`. It should work though if you injected into the method param instead.

To get around this, there is the [`ResourceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html), which when used, should preserve all the injections. For example in your current case, you can do

```
@Path("/categories")
@Produces("application/json")
public static class CategoryResourcesApi {

    @Context
    private ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @Path("/{catId}/products")
    public ProductResourcesApi getProducts() {
        return resourceContext.getResource(ProductResourcesApi.class);
    }
}

@Path("/products")
@Produces("application/json")
public static class ProductResourcesApi {

    @Context
    private UriInfo info;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response getProducts(
            @PathParam("id") String prodId,
            @PathParam("catId") String catId) {
    }
}
```

The `getProducts` would map to the URI `/categories/{catId}/products/{prodId}`. You just need to check if the `catId` is null (only if you need it to do any lookup) I guess to determine if the request is a request to the root products resource or to the parent categories resource. Small price to pay for code reuse I guess.

And just looking at your comment, I believe in the past Swagger didn't support sub-resource locators, but I believe now they do. You may want to search around for any discussions if you have problems with it. [Here's](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/102) a discussion, and [another one](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/924), and [another one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wordnik-api/WUpl961mQlY)

Comment: FYI - you can just return the class (instead of using resourceContext)