# Jersey 2 forward HTTP request

Tags: java, proxy, jersey, jersey-2.0, http-proxy

How to forward an HTTP POST request with headers and body on a Jersey endpoint to an external endpoint without using redirects?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242719/jersey-url-forwarding) does not help as it redirects the request and does not forward it.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330700/jersey-redirect-after-post-to-outside-url) does something similar. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434299/how-to-forward-a-rest-request-to-another-resource) does it for internal endpoints.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). As it stands this question is rather off-topic as it is simply asking for an off-site resource and it is not terribly clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hey @rmlan, is the question better now?

Comment: Why does it need to be Jersey? Jersey is a high-level library for creating RESTful endpoints easily. Generically proxying requests is a much lower-level problem. If you really want to use Java (which I wouldn't recommend), you should probably write a generic servlet that handles all requests.

Comment: It's supposed to be served from a Tomcat container and the endpoint needs to go as a part of an application which already uses Jersey. And I need to serve it from the same origin and it's in an environment where I cannot put up a reverse proxy. Hence the issue.

Comment: Use the Jersey Client